# Variables to be made part of text for print the easy way

Tags: printing

I have the content of appointment letters of a number of employees to be printed in A4 page with variables like name, date of joining, post, salary. I need suggestion regarding software that takes input of the variables and then gives the output for print. The input can be in the form of Excel table (just a hint).

Comment: Have you looked at the "mail merging" feature of software such as LibreOffice? I believe you could use it.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Taking cue from your reply, how about mail merge feature in MS Word. Asking this as it is already installed on my PC.

Comment: I don't have MS Word so I don't know, but you should try it, and if it works, post an answer below :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NicolasRaoul Yes, mailmerge feature of MSWord perfectly fits for the purpose. I think the term mailmerge is misleading and should have been something like textmerge as its name.

Comment: Please click the tick mark to accept this answer, as doing so will help others who read this question in future.